# Am I able to append a % character to the output of an sql update statement?

Tags: sql

I am using a query to update a table field with a percentage, and I wanted to know if there was a way to append a % symbol at the end of the output. My code is as follows:

```
UPDATE TM_SCRIPT_SUMMARY_STATUS SET 
EXEC_PERC_COMP = (SELECT CONVERT(decimal(5, 2),(CONVERT(numeric, EXEC_COMP) / CONVERT(numeric, SCRIPT_TOTAL)) * 100.0)
                 WHERE IMP_NAME = 'TEST RELEASE DEMO' 
                 AND PROJECT_ID = 'testingproject') 
WHERE IMP_NAME = 'TEST RELEASE DEMO' 
AND PROJECT_ID = 'testingproject')
```

Comment: Google "escaping characters in SQL"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting to decimal, try converting to varchar, and append the %.

```
UPDATE tm_script_summary_status 
SET    exec_perc_comp = 
   ( 
          SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), exec_comp) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), script_total)) * 100.0) + '%'
          FROM <tablename>
          WHERE  imp_name = 'TEST RELEASE DEMO' 
          AND    project_id = 'testingproject'
   ) 
WHERE  imp_name = 'TEST RELEASE DEMO' 
AND    project_id = 'testingproject')
```

Comment: Only if the datatype of `exec_perc_comp` allows it (if i'ts a string compatible datatype - `VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR` etc.)

Comment: This code does not work for me, I get the following error: "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar."